# Does Build require for a dependent DLL if virtual function has been added

Tags: c++, dll, virtual-functions

I have a dll having class A.
There is a second dll which use this class A and i have modified my class A by adding a virtual function.
Do i need to build my dll if i access this function in second dll or not.
I hope question is sensible. please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild all the modules and don't tempt fate.

If instances of that class are shared between the DLL's then yes, you need to rebuild all the modules.  This is no different than if you changed the class and only recompiled some of your files that refer to the class.  Something bad will happen at some point.

For example, one module uses (implicitly or explicitly) `sizeof(A)`.  If `A` will be different sizes in different modules, then that is certainly going to be an issue.